# Shopify - Client side order Tagging

Tags: api, shopify

As per the requirements I got, In the Shopify shop, admin should be able to search for the orders from a customer chosen delivery date. The only feasible thing I could find was to tag the orders with their delivery and to filter the orders from the tag. My question is whether there a proper way to tag the orders with a customer given delivery date when a order is created? (I'm not allowed use any paid app/plug-in)

There are two approaches I could figure out with the admin orders API, but both has issues,

1. Write a webhook (for order confirmation event) to an external server that could get the user selected delivery date and call the admin order API from there to tag the order - The issues are it's an overhead to maintain a server only for tagging the order and even if I do since admin API doesn't allow CORS is this feasible?  (and since the shop owner doesn't even want to pay for a paid plugin, maintaining server is also not practical)
2. Call the admin API from the client-side after the order is confirmed. I tried this and it works as it's expected but the issue is I have to keep the admin API credentials for orders and transactions stored in the client-side JavaScript which is not a good practice at all, as per my knowledge.

It's allowed to create additional details about the order at the client side using cart-attributes, and they are shown at the admin order's page as well, but Shoify doesn't allow to search orders using cart-attributes added to the order.

I would be grateful if someone can suggest a solution for this.

Comment: I'm not answering your exact question but If you want to create a Shopify App that has admin pages you must have your own server or hosting because you need a server side language. Also, you should not call the Admin API from the client side,never, because of security concerns.   Also, you should consider and create your report as an embedded page in the the Shopify Admin. Please see this: [ESDK](https://help.shopify.com/api/sdks/shopify-apps/embedded-app-sdk)

Comment: what you meant by having admin pages is to have control over admin pages? Because shopfy also offers admin pages already even with shopify hosted.

Comment: If you are creating admin pages, those should be hosted in your server. Another story is if your modifying the theme, that is the customer pages and you should not use that for administration. Are you trying to create new pages on the theme? With the ESDK you can add new pages to the admin.

Comment: What I wanted is to make the shopify admin order page which is already there to have the functionality of searching orders by their delivery date. This can be already achieved with order tagging, but the sad thing I couldn't figure out a proper way of tagging orders with a user chosen delivery date when the order is created.

Comment: I got it. Well, I think the second option is not a good one and you should go the webhook way or you can have a cron and call the API every hours or something like that, but in both cases your clients needs a server.

Comment: yeah, that's the problem I face. Is this feasible to achieve by writing a shopify app? I'm still looking on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually do this with a Chrome plugin (or really complex bookmarklet) with no server side requirements. see https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview

your api calls would look something like the following POC scripts. [API calls](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/order#index) won't search the order by tags so you could skip that and filter by a note_attribute set via your theme's .liquid code. Your chrome plugin would then list open orders and display them by requested delivery date.

get an existing order and update its note attribute:

```
jQuery.get('/admin/orders/5803440262.json').then(function(d) {
    console.log(d.order);
    var so = {
        id: d.order.id,
        note_attributes: [{
            name: 'Test Value',
            value: 'Test'
        }]
    };
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/admin/orders/' + so.id + '.json',
        type: 'PUT',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            order: so
        }),
        contentType: 'application/json'
    }).then(function(d) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(d, null, ' '));
    });
});
```

and reading orders:

```
jQuery.get('/admin/orders.json?limit=250').then(function(d) {
    var count = 0;
    d.orders.forEach(function(so) {
        if (so.tags.indexOf('__amazon_pending') != -1) count++;
    });
    console.log(count + ' matching orders');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Writing a plugin is a good new approach that I couldn't though of. But it still have some issues as I understood. 1) It forces my client to install the plugin whenever he change the device and limits the freedom of browsing at anytime anywhere as he has to install it if its a new device. 2) I might need to write plugins for all the browsers because I cant be sure that its only chrome that will be used 3) and if its a plugin then it would be different page that shows the list of orders, but I need to get it done in the shopify admins orders page itself.

Comment: If you have those requirements then you'd be better off with a hosted app. 
As far as I know extensions are not supported on Chrome mobile browsers.

Comment: And one note as I feel you didn't understand my problem fully, I managed to get the orders to have a note attribute(I think note attributes and cart attributes refers to the same ) of delivery date at the very point customer selects the date and it is visible in the admins orders page as well. But the issue was i couldn't find a way to search orders by those attributes. That's why I thought of tagging orders which allows to filter orders at the admins page (my problem was how to tag a order at client side, but not how to use the orders API to search orders by a tag)

Comment: No. I understood your issue is that you need to retrieve orders by delivery date. Your problem is finding something that you can do that with. 
However a tag will be static. You can tag with something like "delivery:2017-08-12" but you'd need to change the search every day so while that would work it's not a great way to deal with the issue. An extension or app lets you bring up a window where the filter is relative to today's date.

Comment: yeah, the search need to be changed according to the date. Yes your idea would give a better user experience. I'll consider that as well